# IDEA failed to start a local glassfish server

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm trying to start Glassfish 4.1 in Intellij IDEA 13.1.4. I've set basic settings in Run/debug configurations window - selected application server, jvm, put 2 artifacts to deploy, left startup/connection configurations default. When I try to start it the exception is thrown. Here is full stack trace:

```
 /home/glassfish/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1

   Detected server admin port: 4848
   Detected server http port: 8080
[2014-11-14 03:09:49,839] Artifact ss-ear:ear: Server is no connected.Deploy     is not available.
[2014-11-14 03:09:49,839] Artifact ss-ear:ear exploded: Server is not connected.  Deploy is not available.

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log.lck
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:438)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:318)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:99)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:192)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:228)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:124)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)

 Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
 The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
 Command start-domain failed.
 Before it died, it produced the following output:

 Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
 Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: the domain directory is not writable.
at  com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.verifyDomainRoot(MainHelper.java:246)
at   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.findInstanceRoot(MainHelper.java:349)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:78)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
```

I'm using Ubuntu OS 14.04 LTS, java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64.
Glassfish installed in /home/glassfish, asadmin script have 777 permissions.
Server starts when i run it from terminal, but not from IDE.

Please help, it makes me mad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to start IntelliJ with sudo permission and start the server within the ide?

Comment: Thanks for reply my question, your suggestion particularly solved my issue. But now i have another, it concerns with memory allocation, next run give me this:
 "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000bff80000, 716177408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)."
 Should I change the jdk settings on server?

Answer (score 5):

See this "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" it says all. Give permissions to the gassfish folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /wherever-the-folder-is/glassfish-folder
```

Comment: Thank you. My GlassFish installation located in /opt and after the update chmod permission to 777 everything is worked.

Answer (score 1):

open CMD as Run as Administrator and then start the glassfish domain. so that the domain will start.