# Can not start GlassFish in IntelijIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

```
My Log Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:99)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:192)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:228)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:124)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
```

Comment: Hi, this topic was previously covered in this post : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931211/idea-failed-to-start-a-local-glassfish-server)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lock file on the server.log. GlassFish won't start if it can't write to that log. Try deleting the lock file: `C:\Program Files\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck`

Comment: this file is not in the folder

Comment: It may well be a hidden file. Alternatively, it could be a problem with permissions. Make sure you are running IntelliJ with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the path for your installed Glassfish server:

> C:\Program Files\glassfish4

This directory in Windows need **admin permission** in order to perform edit to **server.log**

**Relocate Glassfish server directory** to get rid of the error, for example move it to:

> C:\glassfish4

As a notice don't forget to edit configuration of Glassfish server inside IntelliJ IDEA.