# IntelliJ IDEA and Glassfish for Java web app

Tags: java, intellij-idea, permissions, glassfish

I am having trouble getting a simple java web app running. I am going through [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#new_project).

I am using: `IntelliJ IDEA ultimate ed. 2023.3.2`

JDK: `19.0.1`

Glassfish: `7.0.9`

I am on part 5 under **Create a GlassFish run configuration**, and when I try to run the configuration I receive this error in my terminal:

```
[2024-01-08 09:54:38,549] Artifact JavaEEHelloWorld:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\glassfish7\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:121)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:304)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:363)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:512)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:342)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:295)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:323)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:33)
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
```

I tried to check the server logs under **Run > Run/Debug Configurations > Logs** but didn't find much.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000975/can-not-start-glassfish-in-intelijidea), but when I searched for files using

`C:\Program Files\glassfish7\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs> dir`

the output was

```
09/26/2023  04:04 PM    <DIR>          .
09/26/2023  04:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  10,581,893,120 bytes free
```

meaning I can't find the lock file. I even tried to search for hidden files but couldn't find it.

On the same post, a different answer says to grant **admin permission** to glassfish4, so in my case it would be *glassfish7*. I did this through simply going to **Properties > security** and the folder had *Read & Execute*, *Read*, and I gave it *Write*. I verified that the folder now has these permissions.

I think that's what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931211/idea-failed-to-start-a-local-glassfish-server) is also saying, as it says to make the permissions 777.

I tried to run the program again, but it gave me the same errors as above.

When I checked the permissions through the command line using

`C:\Program Files> icacls glassfish7`

it returned

```
glassfish7 APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(W)
           NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(F)
           NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(CI)(IO)(F)
           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
           BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
           BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
           CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
           APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(RX)
           APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
           APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(RX)
           APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

and this is where I'm stuck, as I can't make sense of the permissions to verify that *glassfish7* has the right permissions.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Make a new server installation outside the `Program Files` so that IDE can write into this directory.